# How can I notify my user that a read hasn't been completed yet?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I have a class that encapsulates all the business logic related to using Asio to read and write to a generic stream socket. I'd like to add a flag so my users know if they can retrieve data from a getter or whether we're still waiting for the backend.

How is this normally done? Set a flag to busy after the write and do the read in the background in a separate thread? The flag would be something similar to [PQisBusy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-async.html)

Comment: define an event so you give the user a callback when the resources are available....

Comment: Thats one alternative but for now I need to implement the isBusy flag.

Comment: isBusy flag is a way to solve the problem, you will need to do Pooling or long pooling which is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you are looking for an asynchronous solution such as using a callback or a polling method. From the question it seems you are looking for a polling method since you want a flag that users can check to see if the data is fully ready. In that case just define a variable and function in your class, .h file:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>    

class MySocket
{
public:
   ~MySocket();
   bool IsReady();
   void StartDataGather();    
private:
   void GatherDataThread();
   static std::atomic<bool> _isReady;
   std::thread _thread;
}
```

In your .cpp file:

```
#include "MySocket.h"

static std::atomic<bool> MySocket::_isReady(false); // Default flag to false.

MySocket::~MySocket()
{
    // Make sure to kill the thread if this class is destroyed.
    if (_thread.joinable())
        _thread.join();
}

bool MySocket::IsReady() { return _isReady; }

void MySocket::StartDataGather()
{
    _isReady = false; // Reset flag.

    // If your gather thread is running then stop it or wait for it
    // to finish before starting it again.
    if(_thread.joinable())
        _thread.join();

    // Start the background thread to gather data.
    _thread = std::thread(GatherDataThread());
}

void MySocket::GatherDataThread()
{
    // This is your thread that gathers data.
    // Once all of the data is gathered, do the following:
    _isReady = true;
}
```

To use this method from outside of your client class do the following:

```
MySocket mySock;

mySock.StartDataGather();

while(!mySock.IsReady())
{
    // Do some other code here until data is ready.
    // Once the MySocket::GatherDataThread() finishes it will
    // set _isReady = true which will cause mySock.IsReady() to
    // return true.
}
```

You now have a flag that others can check and it is thread safe because of the `std::atomic<>` template. The following uses C++ 11 or newer `-std=c++11`.

Comment: Why did you make _isReady static and not an instance variable?

Comment: In case there are multiple instances of the `MySocket` class. I do not know how your code will be used so I had to guess on a few things. If it is OK to have several instances of the class and the `GatherDataThread` doesn't require a shared resource then you can remove the `static`. Again, it all depends on what you want to do in your code.

Comment: Thanks, this was great!

Answer (score 0):

if by user, you mean user of a library, I would recommend wrapping the result of the asynchronous method in an `std::future` or similar thread synchronization mechanism. You could use the `wait_for` method to fail and notify that the process is still ongoing, then try again.

Comment: tbh I'm not super familiar with boost asio, but I think you're thinking too low level. The result of your library is certainly something other than the direct output of the `async_read`? After the `async_read` callback condition is met, then you can supply the `future` with its result.